# Permission problem to get sub site info

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, client-object-model

i use this code to retrieve all sub sites under one sub site

```
function GroupMenu(url,elem){
var sites = [];
var clientContext =new SP.ClientContext(url);
var webs = clientContext.get_web().get_webs();
clientContext.load(webs);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
  );

  function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        var listItemEnumerator = webs.getEnumerator();

        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var cItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            //console.log(cItem.get_id()+"   ==== "+cItem.get_url());
            var t = cItem.get_title();
            var u = cItem.get_url();


            var site = {
            title:t,
            url:u

            };

            sites.push(site);

        }//end while

        populateMenu(sites,elem,url);

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }


 }
```

it works fine if the Logged user is Admin user if not it gives an alert on the page

```
Request failed. Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

undefined
how can i grant permission for non-admin users to retrieve this info to populate a menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `getSubwebsForCurrentUser`. It will only give those webs on which user has access. There is no sense in populating a menu with name of a site to which user doesn't have access. Change `var webs = clientContext.get_web().get_webs();` to `var webs = clientContext.get_web().getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);`

Comment: Thanks Nadeem your always backup for me :D
thanks bro worked great